# How to configure the Record Sets in Google Cloud?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, google-cloud-platform, dns-zone

I have setup a VM on Google compute engine with a static IP address (say IPv4). Currently I am running two servers on the same VM, one at port 8000 and the other at 5000. I have a domain purchased on GoDaddy.com (say example.com) and I have transferred the name servers to the Google cloud ones. Now I want the two server to map as follows:

1. api.example.com  -> IPv4:8000
2. example.com  -> IPv4:5000

I am not sure how to add the record sets (in DNS section in Google Cloud) in order to obtain this behavior? How can this be done?

Comment: You just put in the IP address. What exactly is confusing here?

Comment: I want to use the domain name instead of the ip addresses. In other words I want to use the left side of the mappings I gave.

Comment: DNS works with IP addresses but not with ports so this behavior can't be achieved by adding resource records. This redirection should be arranged on the web server side. Are you facing difficulties with adding record sets into the Cloud DNS zone?